# connection string

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have created a simple members database in ASP.NET with login and create account features. Can anyone give an example of the correct connection string that I would need to use to connect to this database remotely. Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry im quite new to the site and unaware of how the accept thing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the tag I'm guessing you're using SQL Server 2005. See: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005.

Comment: +1.  that's another nice resource for connection strings.  I've bookmarked it along with mine.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify anything about the database  (is it SQL Server, Access, MySql, etc).
 much less the server name, database name, etc.
However, until specifics are posted, here is a nice general resource for figuring out your connection strings:

http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=81

Comment: Its SQL Server 2005. The server name is .\SQLEXPRESS